# I have extracted a tar file in the wrong directory

Tags: directory, tar

I have extracted a tar file in the wrong directory, and this tar file extracted 200 files. I cannot remove everything from the directory because there are 10 files that are sitting in the directory, and are needed.

Comment: Welcome! You can't identify those ten files?

Comment: Yes, I can identify those 10 files.

Comment: So just move the 10 files to a temp directory, delete everything else and move them back. Isn't that a decent solution for you? You can also read the tar file, collect the names of extracted files and delete those, but simply moving the files you want to keep will be easier.

Comment: Sometimes, doing it by hand with `mc` will be faster than automating it – `Ins` marks files, `F8` deletes them. You can even navigate into the tar file in one panel so you can compare what came from there.

Comment: Are you certain that none of the10 files were overwritten by any files in the archive when you unpacked the archive?

Comment: Those 10 files were not overwritten because they didn't exist when I created the tar file. These 10 files are unique from that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would extract the tar file into an empty directory, `diff --report-identical-files --recursive --brief` the new directory to the erroneous directory, use some sed scripts to extract the wrong names and turn it into a series of `rm` commands, and run that.

My sed script:

```
#!/bin/sh

stdbuf -oL sed -n \
        -e 's/^Files ..*\(\/..*\) and \(..*\1\) are identical$/\2/p' \
        -e 's/^File ..*\(\/..*\) is a socket while file \(..*\1\) is a socket$/\2/p' \
        -e 's/^File ..*\(\/..*\) is a fifo while file \(..*\1\) is a fifo$/\2/p' \
    | stdbuf -oL sed \
        -e s/"'"/"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"/g \
        -e 's/.*/rm   '"'"'&'"'"'/' \
        ;
```

---

An easier solution might be to use `tar -t` to generate the list of files from the .tar file, and remove those.

Perhaps:

```
tar tf tarfilename.tar | xargs rm -i
```

Comment: Risk factor: if the tar contains a file of the same name but not the same actual file. For 10 files, I would tar those 10 for security (into the directory above), *and* also mv them elsewhere, before clearing the corrupted directory. I'm not very brave once I make a mistake -- too easy to compound it.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant  That is only a risk for the "easier solution".  Personally, for something like this, I always use the diff technique.  But, yes, backing up the 10 files is also a good idea.

Comment: Be careful, as `tar -t` may output extra text. The only clean way to get pure file names is to call `star -t -tpath < file.tar`.

Comment: @schily This is one reason I listed `rm -i`   Another is that it will go significantly wrong if whitespace or any special characters xargs interprets is in the filenames.  I do think one is better off with the clean extraction and diff the directories method.  Finally, you really should use the same `tar` that was originally used, as a different tar might extract things differently.

Comment: I'm pretty sure only a broken tar would extract things differently - well as long as the archive was not created with a broken tar implementation. BTW: since `star` comes with a built-in `find` since it uses `libfind`, you may use `star ... -find ... -exec ...` to remove even files with spaces or newlines in the filename.

Comment: @schily  pretty sure I'm right.  Many `tar`s have been extended to handle things like long paths.  (Originally, tar had a 100 byte filename limit.)  If the extensions don't match, things might vary or even go wrong.  This does not make either implementation broken, only different.

Comment: I'm almost positive: `tar` ext. that allow path name lengths up to 8GB are standard since 2001. `tar` extension that allow path names up to 255 bytes are std. since 1988. Before 1988, there've only been three `tar` implementations: `tar` from UNIX from 1977, `star` from 1982 and PG-tar/SUG-tar from the Sun employee John Gilmore from 1987. These implementations all have been carefully designed to not cause problems with the other ones. You will see problems,  when you e.g. unpack with a `tar` that after 19 years has not been updated for POSIX-2001, or an implementation does not unpack own tars